# How Do I Post an Event to a Facebook Fan Page using the PHP SDK and Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

The following code works, but it creates the event as the currently logged-in page administrator. I need it to post the event to the fan page itself. FYI: My app has been granted the permissions scope: `manage_pages`

```
<?php

// Initialize a Facebook instance from the PHP SDK
$config = array(
  'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => false,
  'scope' => 'manage_pages,create_event'
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$page_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';

// Now, getting the PAGE Access token, using the user access token

$page_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id?fields=access_token&" . $access_token;
$response = file_get_contents($page_token_url);

// Parse the return value and get the Page access token
$resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);

$page_access_token = $resp_obj['access_token'];

// Declare the variables we'll use to demonstrate
// the new event-management APIs
$event_id = 0;
$event_name = "New Event API Test Event";
$event_start = time() + rand(1, 100) * rand(24, 64) * 3600;
$event_privacy = "SECRET"; // We'll make it secret so we don't annoy folks.

// We'll create an event in this example.
// We'll need create_event permission for this.
$params = array(
  'name' => $event_name,
  'start_time' => $event_start,
  'privacy_type' => $event_privacy,
  'access_token' => $page_access_token,
  'page_id' => $page_id //where $page_id is the ID of the page you are managing
);

// Create an event
$ret_obj = $facebook->api("/$page_id/events", 'POST', $params);
if(isset($ret_obj['id'])) {
  // Success
  $event_id = $ret_obj['id'];
  printMsg('Event ID: ' . $event_id);
} else {
  printMsg("Couldn't create event.");
}

// Convenience method to print simple pre-formatted text.
function printMsg($msg) {
   echo "<pre>$msg</pre>";
}

?>
```

Comment: I figured it out: I added the parameter `page_id` to the list of `$params` and gave it the value `$page_id` and it took right off! I will post the amended code in case it helps anyone else if I can remember within the next several hours due to my low reputation. Thanks regardless!

Comment: Is this the amended code above? I could really use some help right now! :)

Comment: @JodyHeavener I just updated it for you.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token. thrown in /home/scott/public_html/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1340

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here:
[Facebook PHP API, Post an Event on a Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344622/facebook-php-api-post-an-event-on-a-page)

Copied below for convenience:

I think you need the page access_token and here how you get it:

```
$page_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
$page_access_token = "";
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Make sure you grant the manage_pages permission and add the access_token to the $event_info array.